# Divide a fasta file with scaffolds into same lenght files respecting the scaffold ID and the sequence

Tags: awk, grep, split, csplit

I am currently working with a large fasta file (3.7GB) that has scaffolds in it. Each scaffold has a unique identifier that starts with `>` on the first line and on the consecutive line it has the DNA sequence like this:

```
>9999992:0-108
AAAGAATTGTATTCCCTCCAGGTAGGGGGGATAGTTGAGGGGATACATAG
TGGGAAGGCTTTTCATGCGGAGGGACTAGAATGTGCTCCCGACTGACAAA
GCAGCTTG
>9999993:0-118
AGGGACTAGAAATGAGATTAAAAAGAGTAAAAGCACTGATACAAGTACAA
AAACAAATTGCTTCACCTCCAAAACCCCAGAAACTGCCCCACTTGGCTCC
CATTTAACCTACCTTCAA
>9999994:0-113
CCATCCTCATCCTTTCCTCCCCATATCTTCCTCTGACCCCAAAGCTCAGG
TTTCCTGTCTTGTTTCCCAGAATCTGTACCTCATGGTAGTTAAACCTTCC
CCTCTGGCAGCCA
>9999997:0-87
AACATCCCTGTGGCCTGAGAGACTGCCAGCCACAGCGGTGACAGTCCCTG
CGAGAGGCTGCTGCAAAAAGACTGGAGAGAAAGCAGA
>9999998:0-100
AAACATCAGCGCCAAGTCCCCGAAACCAGCAGGGTCACTGGGCGGCCGGC
CTGAAATACCCCAGCAGGCCAGCAGTGCCGGGTGCCTGGGGAGGTGTCCT
>9999999:0-94
AAGAAACTTTTCCCTTAACCAATGAAGAGTTTTATGTAAAGGAAATTTAG
TAATTTTTTAAAAAATGGTAATGACAGATTTAAGTAATTTAATT
```

I want to split the file into small files preferably of the same length to process it, but I need to respect the ID and the sequence together, and obtain something like this:

```
file1.fa
>9999992:0-108
AAAGAATTGTATTCCCTCCAGGTAGGGGGGATAGTTGAGGGGATACATAG
TGGGAAGGCTTTTCATGCGGAGGGACTAGAATGTGCTCCCGACTGACAAA
GCAGCTTG
>9999993:0-118
AGGGACTAGAAATGAGATTAAAAAGAGTAAAAGCACTGATACAAGTACAA
AAACAAATTGCTTCACCTCCAAAACCCCAGAAACTGCCCCACTTGGCTCC
CATTTAACCTACCTTCAA

file2.fasta
>9999994:0-113
CCATCCTCATCCTTTCCTCCCCATATCTTCCTCTGACCCCAAAGCTCAGG
TTTCCTGTCTTGTTTCCCAGAATCTGTACCTCATGGTAGTTAAACCTTCC
CCTCTGGCAGCCA
>9999997:0-87
AACATCCCTGTGGCCTGAGAGACTGCCAGCCACAGCGGTGACAGTCCCTG
CGAGAGGCTGCTGCAAAAAGACTGGAGAGAAAGCAGA

file3.fasta
>9999998:0-100
AAACATCAGCGCCAAGTCCCCGAAACCAGCAGGGTCACTGGGCGGCCGGC
CTGAAATACCCCAGCAGGCCAGCAGTGCCGGGTGCCTGGGGAGGTGTCCT
>9999999:0-94
AAGAAACTTTTCCCTTAACCAATGAAGAGTTTTATGTAAAGGAAATTTAG
TAATTTTTTAAAAAATGGTAATGACAGATTTAAGTAATTTAATT
```

Please help me. I have tried to use `csplit` and grep but I get the wrong outputs.

Comment: please show what you tried and show the results you got

Comment: *split the file into small files preferably of the same length*? What is the length that you want for each file? 100MB perhaps?

Comment: Could you split the file into several files that contain the same number of `unique identifier` (with its respective DNA) ? I thing that's a possible solution without having to check the length for each file.

Comment: Yes, I would like to split it into 100 MB but with the identifier and the sequence together. and that's a good idea having the same number of unique identifiers the character that identifies them and all of them have in common is '>' I have 3714529 scaffolds so if I divide the whole file into 10 files with 371,453 unique identifiers would be also okay.

Comment: You may not be aware of the Stackexchange Bioinformatics site.  It has multiple questions with answers relating to splitting fasta files: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/search?q=split+fasta  The users of that site would also be able to help you with specialised software for working with fasta files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below might help you but it might be slow for huge files (according to your computer specs).

First, you should get the total of `Unique Identifier`. You can achieve that by using `grep -c`

```bash
total=$(grep -c "^>" largeFastaFile.txt)
```

The code above will assign to `total` variable the count of matching lines that start with `>`.
Now you should get the number of `Unique Identifier` you will have per file.
So if you want to have *10 files*. You should divide `total/10`:

```bash
max=$((total/10))
#If total has 3714529 then max will have 371,452.
```

Finally with `awk` command you can plit your large file in 10 files (**actually 11**) with approximately *371,452 Unique Identifier* per file:

```bash
awk -v maxline=$max -v count=0\ 
 '{if(NR>1) { if( (NR-2)%maxline == 0 ) count++ ; print ">"$0 >("file"count".fasta")  } }'\
 RS='>' largeFastaFile.txt
```

The script should look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

total=$(grep -c "^>" largeFastaFile.txt)
max=$((total/10)) # where 10 is the number of files you will get

awk -v maxline=$max -v count=0 '{if(NR>1) { if( (NR-2)%maxline == 0 ) count++ ; print ">"$0 >("file"count".fasta")  } }' RS='>' largeFastaFile.txt
```

Actually you will get 11 files because if the total is `3714529` and you want 10 files with the same number of `371,452 Unique Identifier` per file then there will be some few lines which will have to be in another file:

```
371,452 * 10 = 3,714,520
```

So the *11th* file will have the last *9 Unique Identifier*

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked

Comment: @NadiaTamayo you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a couple of scripts written by an old colleague years ago to convert between fasta and tbl (sequence identifier, TAB, sequence on a single line) formats. I have posted the scripts [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651/298). Using them, you can easily convert your file to one sequence per line, then split specifying how many lines you want in each file, and then convert the split files back to fasta:

```
FastaToTbl file.fa | split -l 2 - splitFile
```

Using your example input, that creates these files:

```
$ for f in splitFile*; do printf "\n===== File: %s ====\n" "$f"; cat "$f"; done

===== File: splitFileaa ====
9999992:0-108   AAAGAATTGTATTCCCTCCAGGTAGGGGGGATAGTTGAGGGGATACATAGTGGGAAGGCTTTTCATGCGGAGGGACTAGAATGTGCTCCCGACTGACAAAGCAGCTTG
9999993:0-118   AGGGACTAGAAATGAGATTAAAAAGAGTAAAAGCACTGATACAAGTACAAAAACAAATTGCTTCACCTCCAAAACCCCAGAAACTGCCCCACTTGGCTCCCATTTAACCTACCTTCAA

===== File: splitFileab ====
9999994:0-113   CCATCCTCATCCTTTCCTCCCCATATCTTCCTCTGACCCCAAAGCTCAGGTTTCCTGTCTTGTTTCCCAGAATCTGTACCTCATGGTAGTTAAACCTTCCCCTCTGGCAGCCA
9999997:0-87    AACATCCCTGTGGCCTGAGAGACTGCCAGCCACAGCGGTGACAGTCCCTGCGAGAGGCTGCTGCAAAAAGACTGGAGAGAAAGCAGA

===== File: splitFileac ====
9999998:0-100   AAACATCAGCGCCAAGTCCCCGAAACCAGCAGGGTCACTGGGCGGCCGGCCTGAAATACCCCAGCAGGCCAGCAGTGCCGGGTGCCTGGGGAGGTGTCCT
9999999:0-94    AAGAAACTTTTCCCTTAACCAATGAAGAGTTTTATGTAAAGGAAATTTAGTAATTTTTTAAAAAATGGTAATGACAGATTTAAGTAATTTAATT
```

Change the `-l 2` to however many sequences you want per file. Then, iterte over the split files and convert each of them to fasta:

```
c=0
for f in splitFile*; do 
    outFile=file.$((++c)).fa
    TblToFasta "$f" > "$outFile"
done
```

This results in the following files:

```
$ for f in file.*.fa; do printf "\n===== File: %s ====\n" "$f"; cat "$f"; done

===== File: file.1.fa ====
>9999992:0-108 
AAAGAATTGTATTCCCTCCAGGTAGGGGGGATAGTTGAGGGGATACATAGTGGGAAGGCT
TTTCATGCGGAGGGACTAGAATGTGCTCCCGACTGACAAAGCAGCTTG
>9999993:0-118 
AGGGACTAGAAATGAGATTAAAAAGAGTAAAAGCACTGATACAAGTACAAAAACAAATTG
CTTCACCTCCAAAACCCCAGAAACTGCCCCACTTGGCTCCCATTTAACCTACCTTCAA

===== File: file.2.fa ====
>9999994:0-113 
CCATCCTCATCCTTTCCTCCCCATATCTTCCTCTGACCCCAAAGCTCAGGTTTCCTGTCT
TGTTTCCCAGAATCTGTACCTCATGGTAGTTAAACCTTCCCCTCTGGCAGCCA
>9999997:0-87 
AACATCCCTGTGGCCTGAGAGACTGCCAGCCACAGCGGTGACAGTCCCTGCGAGAGGCTG
CTGCAAAAAGACTGGAGAGAAAGCAGA

===== File: file.3.fa ====
>9999998:0-100 
AAACATCAGCGCCAAGTCCCCGAAACCAGCAGGGTCACTGGGCGGCCGGCCTGAAATACC
CCAGCAGGCCAGCAGTGCCGGGTGCCTGGGGAGGTGTCCT
>9999999:0-94 
AAGAAACTTTTCCCTTAACCAATGAAGAGTTTTATGTAAAGGAAATTTAGTAATTTTTTA
AAAAATGGTAATGACAGATTTAAGTAATTTAATT
```

---

The two scripts used are:

- FastaToTbl

  ```c
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    {
            if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
            if (NR>1)
                        printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
            else 
                printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
            else 
                    printf "%s", $0
    }END{printf "\n"}
  ```
- TblToFasta

  ```c
    #! /usr/bin/awk -f
    {
      sequence=$NF

      ls = length(sequence)
      is = 1
      fld  = 1
      while (fld < NF)
      {
         if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
         printf "%s " , $fld

         if (fld == NF-1)
          {
            printf "\n"
          }
          fld = fld+1
      }
      while (is <= ls)
      {
        printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
        is=is+60
      }
    }
  ```

Save those in your `$PATH` and make them executable.